# How to pre-populate email in the Stripe payments dialog popup

Tags: stripe-payments

I cannot seem to find a way to pre-populate the email address in the stripe payment popup. However this weekend I signed up for two accounts on websites that use stripe payments and I realized those websites had my email pre-populated in the stripe dialog iframe box. So I know there must be a way but I am unsure of how to do that. The docs don't define that property. 
Can someone explain how this is done using the javascript API and the basic Stripe dialog?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're using [Simple Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) you pass the email in `data-email` like this:

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-email="customer@email.com"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

If you're using [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) you pass the email in the `email` parameter to `handler.open()`:

```
handler.open({
  name: 'Stripe.com',
  description: '2 widgets',
  amount: 2000,
  email: "customer@email.com"
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to pre-populate email using Stripe Apple Pay?

Comment: Might be good to know that if you pass an invalid email address (such as "admin") it won't be pre-filled at all.

Comment: Don't forget the comma at the end of the second-to-last line. (Like I did just now)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically set the email (for Simple Checkout ) using js you must dynamically create the whole script element to make sure it loads properly. This can be done like this:

```
//create our stipe script element
var stripescript = document.createElement('script'); //create script element

//dynamicaly load stripe checkout attributes
stripescript.setAttribute('src','https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js');
stripescript.setAttribute("data-key","[YOUR STRIPE TOKEN]" )  
stripescript.setAttribute("data-amount","90" )  
stripescript.setAttribute("data-locale","auto")  
stripescript.setAttribute("class","stripe-button")  
stripescript.setAttribute("data-billing-address",true)  
stripescript.setAttribute("data-panel-label","Update")  
stripescript.setAttribute("data-currency","gbp")  
// any other attributes you want to add stripescript.setAttribute("[name]","[value]") 

//insert script element inside of div or an other element
document.getElementById('[ID OF ELEMENT YOU WANT TO PUT THE FORM INTO]').appendChild(stripescript);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Simple Checkout:
If you chose to use the **stripe-buy-button** element, you can add the *customer-email* property. Getting for example:

```
<stripe-buy-button
  buy-button-id={{STRIPE_BUY_ID}}
  publishable-key={{STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}}
  customer-email={{email}}
>
</stripe-buy-button>
```

In my case, I had used the email for checking in python, so I took the opportunity to pass it on as a context.

If the publishable-key is hardcoded in the HTML, I suggest putting the customer-email before it (for me it didn't recognize the property)
But when I passed the publishable-key through Python, the order of the properties doesn't matter.

Buy button properties: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/buy-button#attributes-to-customize-checkout